# avconv stream video from USB webcam without delay

Tags: video, streaming, webcam, libav, rtmp

I need to stream video from USB webcam. I am using avconv, but it has delay min 5s.

Is possible to stream in real time without delay?

```
avconv -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec libx264 -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.2:1234

avconv -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vcodec libx264 -f flv rtmp://192.168.1.2:1234/test
```

Comment: You should read the section on "Latency" in the [FFMPEG Streaming Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#Latency)